# useEffect of children component called before useEffect of parent

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I am trying to understand why the `useEffect` of a children component gets called before the Parent component `useEffect`.

From my understanding, `useEffect` shoulde be called in the order they are defined based on React's [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-use-multiple-effects-to-separate-concerns):

> React will apply every effect used by the component, in the order they were specified.

This would mean, a Parent's `useEffect` should be called before a Children's `useEffect`, but this is not the case.

Example:

```
const MainComponent = () => {
  return {
    <ParentComponent />
      
}

const ParentComponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('parent');
  }, []);
  return <div>Parent <ChildrenComponent /></div>;
}

const ChildrenComponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('children');
  }, []);
  return <div>Children</div>; 
}
```

If you check the console, you should see first `children` and then `parent`

Live Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-butterfly-yn046?file=/src/App.js

My gut tells me this has to do with how react does `Layout` and `Paint` of the Parent-Children components?

Comment: hi did you find any solution to this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76217863/using-useeffect-with-react-router-execute-out-of-order

Answer (score 1):

This:

> React will apply every effect used by the component, in the order they were specified.

Would be more precisely stated as:

> React will apply every effect used by the component, in the order they were specified in that component.

For example:

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('This will run first');
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('This will run second');
  });
  // ...
```

is guaranteed to run in order.

It's not saying anything about the order that effects *in different components* run.